# Grabbing the name of a numpy structured array column when passed as a parameter to a function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

When trying to use a numpy.array (a structured numpy array) I know I can pull up a column by doing something like array["col"]. From my understanding, this is because of numpy.dtype.names and the nature of structured arrays. However, when passing said array into a function, I don't get the column name when using numpy.dtype.name, I get something like "strxxx". If it helps to know, this particular array was created using numpy.genfromtxt() and a csv file. For example, the below code

```
def empty_check(param):
for ind in param:
    # Ignore future warning for comparison just for this instance
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
        if ind == '':
            print("Please fill out required data in", param.dtype.name, "column")
```

results in:

```
Please fill out required data in str544 column
```

Would anyone have an idea as to why str544 comes up instead of the name of the column?

**Setup**
Python 3.7.0
numpy 1.15.4
IDE: PyCharm 2018.3

Comment: `np.array.dtype.names` is a tuple with the names of your columns. You can loop through the tuple using `enumerate` or `zip`, or you can point to a `param.dtype.names[n]` with a specific index, depending on what you want to do. I only pointed out your mistaking between `name` and `names` (as answered below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a small mistake here.  You're assuming that `dtype.name` and `dtype.names` return the same thing.  They do not.

[From the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html)

> `name`
> A bit-width name for this data-type.
>
> `names` Ordered list of field names, or None if there are no fields.

---

So what you're seeing is the bit-width name for the data type of your field.  However, if you called `dtype.names`, you would be returned `None`, as the *single field* you have passed does not have any fields to return.

---

As far as I know, there is not a way to infer the name of a field without access to the structured array that contains it.  You will most likely have to pass the field name as a parameter to your `empty_check` function.

Comment: I see what you mean here, but would you have any idea how to get the field name when the array is passed to the function as a parameter?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible.  You might have to pass the field name as a separate parameter